# get page source as string from webpage with filled formular. asp.net mvc 2

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2

in my webpage i can fill some form with user information.

http://hotcont.eu/OnlineVertrag/EContract

after filling it i can see it again if all is filled like i wanted. now it should be send to partner.

my question, how can i read html page source of this page with filled user information inside?

i want to get page source as string an send it as HTML Body with MailMessage.

```
<tr>
                    <td style="width: 400px;">
                        <b style="font-size: smaller; color: #00008B;">
                            <%= Html.DisplayFor(model => model.NameSeller) %></b>
                        <p style="margin-top: 3px; border-top: solid 1px #fddf99; width: 300px;">
                            Vorname, Nachname</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b style="font-size: smaller; color: #00008B;">
                            <%= Html.DisplayFor(econtract => econtract.NameBuyer)%></b>
                        <p style="margin-top: 3px; border-top: solid 1px #fddf99; width: 308px;">
                            Vorname, Nachname</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/29407) which illustrates how you could render a view to a string by passing it a model that you have retrieved after your form was submitted.

And if you are using MVC 3 you may take a look at [MvcMailer](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide) which is designed exactly for this purpose.

Comment: what does it mean <T> here??--------------------------------------------------->                                   protected string RenderViewToString<T>(string viewPath, T model) {
  ViewData.Model = model;
  using (var writer = new StringWriter()) {
    var view = new WebFormView(viewPath);
    var vdd = new ViewDataDictionary<T>(model);

Comment: T is your the view model that you need to pass to the view. It is the view model your view is strongly typed to.